# check if url points to a web page and not something else as a file php

Tags: php, http, curl, header

I am using curl to check whether an url is online:

```
$url='http://www.gooogle.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($retcode==200) {
echo'ok';
} else {
echo'not ok';
}
```

I am missing how to know if the url is pointing to a web page and not to something else, such as a file, could be a .jpg or .png instead of a web page and I want to make sure it is a web page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect content type by using [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php). For example:

```
if ($retcode==200) {
    echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
}
```

Comment: would text/html be the content type I'd be looking for if I want a webpage, is there any other similar content type that also matches that of a web page